# Postgresql explain alter table add column doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, explain

I'm using Postgresql 12 (AWS RDS) and pgAdmin4.

While the following statement works

`explain select * from table "Commands";`

The next one

`explain alter table "Commands" drop column "test";`

gives this error

```
LINE 1: explain alter table "Commands" drop column "test";
                ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 9
```

I made sure the statement `alter table "Commands" drop column "test"` itself can be run successfully so this cannot be an issue with that statement.

Does `explain` not work with `alter` or am I missing anything?

Comment: Why do you think you need to see the execution plan of an `alter` statement? What is the underlying problem are you trying to solve by that?

Comment: I'm noob to DB :(. I just learned about the `explain` statement so I wanted to try it with the alter. `Why do you think you need to see the execution plan of an alter statement?` - Guess I need to understand what "Execution plan" is. Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It would be nice if you could EXPLAIN an ALTER in order to see if it would rewrite the table, or if it would just update metadata.  That doesn't work, but it is not non-sensical.

Comment: Now that I understand more about execution plan, I understand why a normal person wouldn't want to `explain` and `alter`. Execution plan is mostly about figuring out the best way to **finding something** (apparent with `SELECT` OR `UPDATE` on a column with/without `INDEX`). So it doesn't make sense to `explain` `ALTER` because `ALTER` is not concerned with **finding something**. However, @jjanes pointed out exactly what I was hoping `EXPLAIN` would be able to do - to explicitly say if the table will be rewritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html, there is no `EXPLAIN` for `ALTER` command.

> Important: Keep in mind that the statement is actually executed when
> the ANALYZE option is used. Although EXPLAIN will discard any output
> that a SELECT would return, other side effects of the statement will
> happen as usual. If you wish to use EXPLAIN ANALYZE on an INSERT,
> UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE TABLE AS, or EXECUTE statement without letting
> the command affect your data, use this approach:

```
statement
```

> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, VALUES, EXECUTE, DECLARE, or
> CREATE TABLE AS statement, whose execution plan you wish to see.

```
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE statement;
ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: I read this part. Actually, I don't think it explicitly mentioned anywhere that `explain` does not support `alter`.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) clearly stats:

> `statement`
>
> Any `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `VALUES`, `EXECUTE`, `DECLARE`, `CREATE TABLE AS`, or `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` AS statement, whose execution plan you wish to see.

Other statements are not supported.